# Changing the Track-bar's Maximum Value

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar

I have a text-box with the intention of entering integers. This integer is supposed to affect all 6 track-bars I have connected with each other, with the track-bar's maximum value all become addends to the entered integer.
For example; If I were to enter 318 into the first text-box, all 6 track-bar's maximum should be 318. If one track-bar's value is 67, then all of the bar's maximum should be 251, and so forth.

I have written all the code for this except that all 6 Track-Bar's Maximum value will not change when starting the program from it's default status. I've tried changing the event to be public instead of private, and putting the code in the public Form1() instead of an event but to no avail. What do I do? Here is an example of an event for one of the sliders I have.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
        Foo();


    }
    public void Foo()
    {
        basetotal.Text = "600";
        hpvalue.Text = "0";
        attackvalue.Text = "0";
        defensevalue.Text = "0";
        speedvalue.Text = "0";
        specialattackvalue.Text = "0";
        specialdefensevalue.Text = "0";
        hpslider.Minimum = 0;
        hpslider.TickFrequency = 100;
        hpslider.LargeChange = 1;
        double total, hp, attack, defense, speed, spa, spd, max;
        total = double.Parse(basetotal.Text);
        hp = double.Parse(hpvalue.Text);
        attack = double.Parse(attackvalue.Text);
        defense = double.Parse(defensevalue.Text);
        speed = double.Parse(speedvalue.Text);
        spa = double.Parse(specialattackvalue.Text);
        spd = double.Parse(specialdefensevalue.Text);
        max = total - hp - attack - defense - speed - spa - spd;
        hpslider.Maximum = (int)max;
        attackslider.Maximum = (int)max;
        defenseslider.Maximum = (int)max;
        speedslider.Maximum = (int)max;
        specialattackslider.Maximum = (int)max;
        specialdefenseslider.Maximum = (int)max;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public void hpslider_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Foo();
    }
```

Comment: If I had to guess, for the case where it doesn't work, the code is probably running when the various controls don't have an expected value in them...like they might be blank?  Since this code will be run for whenever a slider or textbox changes, I'd move that code to a common method and simply call that method from the various TextChange/ValueChanged event handlers.  Call that method from the Shown() event of the form to make sure all the controls have fully loaded and have a good value in them.

Comment: Their values I set them to 0 by default. I am a bit confused on what you mean by common method. Do you mean changing it to a public form, or editing the class?

Comment: You have six different sliders right?  You probably have that same code in all six event handlers.  Move that code out to a different method, then call that method from the event handlers.  Now you can call that method directly from the Shown() event.

Comment: How do I call methods from event handlers? Is it a public void within a class?

Comment: For instance, if your method was called "Foo", you'd do: `public void hpslider_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) { Foo(); }`.   And that method: `public void Foo() { // ... code in here ... }`.

Comment: The code is in public Form1(), and it says I can't treat Form1 like a method when I try that.

Comment: `Public Form1()` is the constructor.  You don't want the code there as the controls may not have been created and added to your form yet.  Use the Load() or Shown() event of the Form, call it from there.

Comment: I did all of this and it gave me the same result of the Maximum values not updating when the event said it changed. It did clean things up however

Comment: Post more complete code and I'll take a peek.

Comment: Edited original comment to post new code. It is the same thing for the rest of the 5 sliders.

Comment: You're using `double`.  Can your stats really have decimal portions like 3.5?  Or are the integral in nature?

Comment: Integers/Whole Numbers only, is there something wrong with double?

Comment: I played with this a bit yesterday but the whole concept is still bothering me.  How do the TextBoxes interact with the sliders?  If the trackbar maximum has been changed, the user could still enter a value higher than that in the corresponding textbox.  Can you describe more how all the components work together?